# MySQL Syntax in creating Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Is this syntax correct in creating a Foreign Key?

```
create table department
(
  departmentID int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(30)
) type=InnoDB;

create table employee
(
  employeeID int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(80),
  job varchar(30),
  departmentID int not null references department(departmentID)
) type=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Why don't you just try? mysql is better in checking the syntax than any person here

Comment: @zerkms Im asking this because I have an eBook which shows that this is the right way of creating the foreign key--contrary of what **Doug** said _It looks like MySQL accepts it (doesn't complain about the syntax) but the foreign key is not actually created._

This isn't the way my instructor taught me. That's why I've tried to verify whether this way is acceptable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like MySQL accepts it (doesn't complain about the syntax) but the foreign key is not actually created.

To create this foreign key, run this command:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT fk_department FOREIGN KEY (departmentID) REFERENCES department (departmentID);
```

Comment: How about my ebook's explanation of creating foreign key. 
_"There is only one new piece of syntax in this statement. The last column in the employee table is the id of the department for which the employees work. This is a foreign key. We declare this in the table definition by adding the references clause as follows:

departmentID int not null references department(departmentID)

This tells us that the departmentID in the employee table should be referenced back to the departmentID column in the department table."_

What can you say about it?

Comment: I tried the code myself and the table was created with your code, but the referencial integrity was not enforced until I created the foreign key separately, with the code I provided in the answer.

Comment: What is `CONSTRAINT` in SQL?... I tried googling the answer but I couldn't find clear definition for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @aer "no two rows in the table can have the same value for the columns. Primary keys also enforce uniqueness, but primary keys do not allow for NULL as one of the unique values"

Answer (score 5):

```
create table employee
(
  employeeID int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(80),
  job varchar(30),
  departmentID int not null ADD CONSTRAINT fk_department FOREIGN KEY (departmentID) references department(departmentID)
)
```

Comment: Welcome! why is this answer better than the accepted one, after 2 years?

Answer (score 1):

```
FOREIGN KEY (departmentID) REFERENCES department(departmentID)
```

Thanks.!