# insert array data into two table using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a registration form and will inserting data inputed into two different table using registration function.
This is the table structure:

**user**

- user_id(int)
- user_email(varchar(64))
- user_name(varchar(64))
- user_pass(varchar(64))

**profiles**

- prof_id(int)
- user_id(int)
- first_name(varchar(64))
- last_name(varchar(64))
- ...(other field)

I put the variables into two different array (**$data1 & $data2**)
here is my controller:

```
function add_account() {
    $this->load->model('m_signup');
    // get form variable
    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
    $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $user_pass = $this->input->post('user_pass');


    $data1 = array($user_name, $user_email, $user_pass);
    $data2 = array($first_name, $last_name);

    $this->m_signup->add_account($data1, $data2);

    redirect('login');
}
```

and the model was like this:

```
function add_account($data1, $data2) {
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_email, user_pass) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $this->db->query($sql1, $data1); 
    $id_user = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO profiles(user_id, first_name, last_name) 
            VALUES ($id_user, ?, ?)"; 
    $this->db->query($sql2, $data2);

    return $this->db->insert_id(); 

    $this->db->trans_complete(); 

}
```

When I submit the registration, its work in table **users**, but the table **profiles** still going empty. Please help me correct my **add_account function** above.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange the lines:  Line  `$this->db->trans_complete();` is not reachable.

You are returning id before committing  the transaction.

```
 $this->db->trans_complete(); 

 return $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: thanks kumar, could you give me a guidance how to join both table using user_id as foreign key

Comment: Are asking for getting record from two table? Or do you want to create foreign key?

Comment: I wanna create foreign key in users table so I can do CRUD operations in my models.

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977086/mysql-syntax-in-creating-foreign-key

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
function add_account() {
    $this->load->model('m_signup');
    // get form variable


    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
    $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $user_pass = $this->input->post('user_pass');


    $data1 = array($user_name, $user_email, $user_pass);

    

    $data1_id = $this->m_signup->add_account($data1);


    $data2 = array($data1_id,$first_name, $last_name,);

    $data_id = $this->m_signup->add_account($data2,$data1_id);

    redirect('login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in model

```
function add_account($data1 = '', $data2 = '' , $id = '') {
    $this->db->trans_start();

    if(empty($id)){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_email, user_pass) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $this->db->query($sql1, $data1); 
    $id_user = $this->db->insert_id(); 

    }else{
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO profiles(user_id, first_name, last_name) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 
    $this->db->query($sql2, $data2);
    }
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 

    $this->db->trans_complete(); 

    }
```